# Trouble Installing PHP enviroment on eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, installation

I am trying to set up the **PHP** enviroment on Eclipse. I am currently using Eclipse version *4.12.0*. I initially installed Eclipse for java but was able to add other different types of projects such as python and Dynamic Web projects(java servlets,jsp etc) with no problem. Trying to do the same with PHP, I installed PHP development tools via `help->install` new software. This is where I run into trouble. I do see the ability to create a new PHP project but when I click to create one I get the following error:

```sh
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.org/eclipse/dltk/internal/ui/dialogs/StatusInfo
```

I am probably missing additional information in which to help with my problem, if so feel free to point it out.

```sh
A snippet from the error log:<br>
       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/dltk/internal/ui/dialogs/StatusInfo
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.preferences.includepath.AbstractIncludepathsBlock.<init>(AbstractIncludepathsBlock.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.preferences.includepath.PHPIncludePathsBlock.<init>(PHPIncludePathsBlock.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.wizards.PHPProjectWizardSecondPage.createBuildpathBlock(PHPProjectWizardSecondPage.java:652)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.ui.wizards.CapabilityConfigurationPage.getBuildPathsBlock(CapabilityConfigurationPage.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.ui.wizards.CapabilityConfigurationPage.createControl(CapabilityConfigurationPage.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.wizards.PHPProjectWizardSecondPage.createControl(PHPProjectWizardSecondPage.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.Wizard.createPageControls(Wizard.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.createPageControls(WizardDialog.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.setWizard(WizardDialog.java:1183)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.updateForPage(WizardDialog.java:1236)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.lambda$3(WizardDialog.java:1224)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.showPage(WizardDialog.java:1224)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardSelectionPage.advanceToNextPageOrFinish(NewWizardSelectionPage.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.NewWizardNewPage.lambda$0(NewWizardNewPage.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:776)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1203)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(OpenStrategy.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4131)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1056)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3944)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3547)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler$New.executeHandler(WizardHandler.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WizardHandler.execute(WizardHandler.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction.runWithEvent(CommandAction.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4131)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1056)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3944)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3547)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.dltk.internal.ui.dialogs.StatusInfo cannot be found by org.eclipse.php.ui_3.0.1.v201201110400
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 78 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You have ancient PDT installed (3.0.1), it was released in 2012! Eclipse 4.12 (2019-06) should contain PDT 6.2.

Recent PDT is 7.0 released with Eclipse 2019-12. It contain support for PHP 7.4 and some other improvements.